# Inappropriate Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

This is a high quality post?

[image: High Quality Post]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19983661

Really bad audit, please adjust.

Comment: We could use some context here...

Comment: @Makoto I am just suggesting to remove that audit to someone who can do it. No context needed for that.

Comment: We *really* could use some context for the review.  At face value, yeah, I'd probably agree with you, but given that it has thirteen upvotes, there *may* be more to it than what you're thinking.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe, I am not asking to remove the answer, perhaps it's useful to someone. But in a review context I can justify to vote it down, so it is not a good choice for an audit

Comment: Casting a down vote on the answer would prevent it from being an audit; however it looks like you didn't do that after failing the audit. Since the post has already been improved by two edits it doesn't look like anything more needs to happen.

Comment: It seems that answer solved the problem - for the OP and for several visitors. It has room for improvements, but it is useful. No need for downvotes IMO. It's not a great audit, but not a particularly bad one, either.